# Android step by step math solver that includes fractions

Tags: android, math, calculator

I want a calculator app that shows fractions on the way to an answer...
like
2X+3=10
2X=10-3
2X=7
X=7/2
X=3.2
It would be good if I can type fractions with long bars... I mean not like 35+235/476.. but with a long bar under 35+235....
Does one like that exist? Searching on the internet didn't help me
thanks....
And typing only above contents wouldn't let me post the question

Answer (score 1):

I would see if Symbolab could work for you. It's free to download and very easy to use. They also have [a website](https://www.symbolab.com/) too that provides the same solutions as well.

## [Symbolab - Math solver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devsense.symbolab)

> Your private math tutor, solves any math problem with steps! Symbolab
> calculator solves: Algebra Equations, Integrals, Limits, Derivatives,
> Functions & Graphing, Trigonometry, Series, ODE, Laplace Transform,
> and Matrices & Vectors
>
> [image: Symbolab Android UI]